# Get Bootstrap 3.7 buttons to align horizontally

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I'm sure this problem is not new....to anyone.

I have a standard three column layout with a title, a body and several buttons for each column. My problem is the buttons. They are lined up horizontally when the second column within a viewport **bigger** than 768px. I am using a HTML `<br>`, which I feel is not professional/efficient. But I would prefer finding a better way to get the buttons to align **horizontally** within varied viewports. I feel like I'm making this harder than it needs to be. See page and change the viewport below 768px to see what I mean. This is the page I mean:
http://mpactchurches.com/growth-track-downloads/

any ideas? Forgive me if has been asked a million times!

See below code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row" id="gallery">
        <div style="margin-top:2%;"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12"> <p> Manna Church has made it's complete Growth Track available for download, free of charge. Feel free to download individual sessions or whole packages as needed.</p> 
        </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-top: 8%;">
              <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;" ><span style="color:#f05a38;">First</span>Step</h2>
                    <p>FirstStep introduces the basic healthy habits essential to a fruitful walk with Jesus, and also discusses baptism and its importance. A four-week Small Group.</p>

              <div style="padding-top: 3%;" class="text-center">
              <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/First+Step.zip" alt="Complete download"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Complete FirstStep Package (5.1 GBs)</button></a>

              <hr>
                  <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/8.5x11_first+step.pdf" alt="FirstStep PDF"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">FirstStep Booklet &#8226; 8.5 x 11 PDF</button></a><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek1-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 1 download">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 1 (1.1 GBs)</button></a>
                  <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek2-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek2-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 2 (1.3 GBs)</button></a>
                  <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek3-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Week 3 (1.2 GBs)</button></a>
                  <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek4-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Week 4 (1.4 GBs)</button></a>

              </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-top: 8%;">

              <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" ><span style="color:#f05a38;">Next</span>Step</h2>    
                  <p>Teach your members and attendees what your church is passionate about, where you're going, and how they can be part of that adventure. A four-week Small Group.</p><div style="padding-top: 3%;" class="text-center"><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/NextStep/Next+Step.pdf" alt="Complete download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Complete NextStep Package (6.6 GBs)</button></a>

              <hr>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/NextStep/8.5x11_+next+step.pdf" alt="NextStep PDF"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">NextStep Booklet &#8226; 8.5 x 11 PDF</button></a>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/NextStep/NextStep+Pt+1-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 1 download"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 1 (1.3 GBs)</button></a>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/NextStep/NextStepPt2-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 2 download" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 2 (2.2 GBs) </button></a>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/NextStep/Next+Step+Pt+3-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 3 (1.5 GBs)</button></a>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/NextStep/Next+Step+Pt+4-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 4 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 4 (1.4 GBs)</button></a>
              </div>    

          </div>


          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" style="margin-top: 8%;">

              <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;" ><span style="color:#f05a38;">Leader</span>Step</h2>
              <p>Equip your church members to lead and influence others in their families, jobs, communities, and at church. An eight-week Small Group.<span style="color:#f05a38;">&#x2731;</span></p>
              <div style="padding-top: 3%;" class="text-center">
              <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStep.zip" alt="Complete download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Complete LeaderStep Package (11.3 GBs)</button></a>

              <hr>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/8.5x11+leaders+step.pdf" alt="NextStep PDF"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">LeaderStep Booklet &#8226; 8.5 x 11 PDF</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek1-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 1 download"> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Week 1 (1.7 GBs)</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek2-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 2 download" ><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 2 (1.4 GBs) </button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek3-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download"> <button
                       class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Week 3 (1.4 GBs)</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek4-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 4 download"><button
                      class="btn btn-default"  type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 4 (1.6 GBs)</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek5-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 5 download"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 5 (1.2 GBs)</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek6-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 6 download"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">&nbsp;Week 6 (1.0 GB)&nbsp;</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek7-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 7 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 7 (1.5 GBs)</button></a>
                      <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/LeaderStep/LeaderStepWeek8-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 8 download"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> Week 8 (1.2 GBs)</button></a>

              <span class="text-center">

              </div>
              <div style="margin-top:10%;"></div>
              <p><span style="color:#f05a38;">&#x2731;</span> We suggest that completion of NextStep and your church's membership application process be required before attending LeaderStep.</p>

              </span>

          </div>
          <div style="margin-top:20%;"></div>



      </div> <!-- END ROW -->

</div> <!-- END CONTAINER  -->
            <div class="container-fluid" > 

              <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

              <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;" target="_blank" ><span style="color:#f05a38;">EDITABLE</span> FILES</h2>
                <p>Need to customize your content? We have provided all our Growth Track content in an editable package so you can adjust everything to meet your church's needs.</p>

                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div style="margin-top:5%;"></div>
                <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxpIAwsSdmG5Z3JtWmc0Nk15TmM?usp=sharing"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Center Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Access Editable Files</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

<div style="margin-top:30%;"></div>
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include relevant code

Comment: I have made small changes to the amount of text in each column so they each align horizontally and responsively, but I think my question still stands. I'm sure other people have run into this problem. Any help would be tremendous -- signed, a web novice trying to be a master.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I'm assuming you want them to stack vertically when the viewport is bigger than 768px. You can put your `<a>` in a `<div>`

This is the First Step column:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="margin-top: 8%;">
            <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;"><span style="color:#f05a38;">First</span>Step</h2>
            <p>FirstStep introduces the basic healthy habits essential to a fruitful walk with Jesus, and also discusses baptism and its importance. A four-week Small Group.</p>
            <div style="padding-top: 3%;" class="text-center">
                <div>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/First+Step.zip" style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="btn btn-default" alt="Complete download">
                    Complete FirstStep Package (5.1 GBs)
                </a>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/8.5x11_first+step.pdf" alt="FirstStep PDF" class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-bottom:10px;">FirstStep Booklet &#8226; 8.5 x 11 PDF</button>
                </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek1-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" class="btn btn-default" alt="Week 1 download" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                      Week 1 (1.1 GBs)
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek2-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" class="btn btn-default" alt="Week 3 download" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                       Week 2 (1.3 GBs)
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek3-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    Week 3 (1.2 GBs)
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gt-downloads/FirstStep/FirstStepWeek4-Apple+Devices+HD+(Best+Quality).m4v" alt="Week 3 download" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    Week 4 (1.4 GBs)
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You should also stop using `<button>` inside of `<a>`, you can always apply the class to the anchor tag itself

Comment: Look at this page for an example using your code. I would cut and paste it, but this editor will not allow me to paste the whole snippet because of character limitations. Review this page:

http://mpactchurches.com/test/

Immeadiately you'll see what I mean. Because the paragraphs at the top all have varied amounts of characters, the buttons underneath never align horizontally. Vertically, no problem. Horizontally, no problem. My question is there a way with bootstrap to make the buttons align horizontally despite varied paragraph lengths?

Comment: @Greg I think I understand what you mean now. Because of varying paragraph lengths the top buttons dont align. You can always put your title and `p`s in their own wrapper div and the buttons in a separate wrapper div.

Comment: Which class of bootstrap would you use for that? Can you grant me using the example of that code, I provided if that's not too much to ask?